# MySQL, combine several queries in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
field_1  field_2  field_3
-------  -------  -------
      3        1        5
      2        1        1
      1        2        1
      1        4        1
```

And I have these 3 queries:

```
select count(*) as field_1_is_2 from my_table where field_1 = 2;
select count(*) as field_2_is_4 from my_table where field_2 = 4;
select count(*) as field_3_is_5 from my_table where field_3 = 5;
select count(*) as fields_combined from my_table where field_3 != 2 and field_2 != 2;
```

How can I combine the above queries in one query?

One option could be:

```
select
  sum(if(field_1 = 2, 1, 0)) as field_1_is_2,
  sum(if(field_2 = 4, 1, 0)) as field_2_is_5,
  sum(if(field_3 = 5, 1, 0)) as field_3_is_5,
  sum(if(field_3 != 2 and field_2 != 2, 1, 0)) as fields_combined
from my_table;
```

But the table is very big and I want to use a proper use of indexes and this approach is not making use of them.

This is the table descripton:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `field_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_field_1` (`field_1`),
  KEY `index_field_2` (`field_2`),
  KEY `index_field_3` (`field_3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So, the question is, How can I combine (if possible) the above queries in one query and making proper use of the indexes?

#### Update

As @ralf.w [is mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40292118/316700) there is a index missing in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD KEY `index_field_2_and_3` (`field_2`,`field_3`);
```

Comment: You covered both choices, you can do 5 queries or you can use sum and case statements (I believe you meant `case` not `if` in your 3rd code sample.)

Comment: You can use `union all` to combine it into one query.

Comment: Is your version with `if` actually slower than the 4 other queries combined? `fields_combined` requires a full table scan anyway, so you should not win that much by not having to evaluate the conditional sums but instead have to query 3 additional times (with index, but still needing time). If you limit yourself to queries that can use indexes, you could `join` them to get them as columns like your `if`-version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version would look like this:

```
select
(select count(*) as field_1_is_2 from my_table where field_1 = 2) as field_1_is_2,
(select count(*) as field_2_is_4 from my_table where field_2 = 4) as field_2_is_4,
(select count(*) as field_3_is_5 from my_table where field_3 = 5) as field_3_is_5,
(select count(*) as fields_combined from my_table 
where field_3 != 2 and field_2 != 2) as fields_combined;
```

and let the rest be optimized and combined by the optimizer.

Executed prepended by EXPLAIN we see this:

1, PRIMARY, , , , , , , , No tables used
5, SUBQUERY, my_table, ALL, index_field_2,index_field_3, , , , 4, **Using where**
4, SUBQUERY, my_table, ref, index_field_3, index_field_3, 5, const, 1, Using index
3, SUBQUERY, my_table, ref, index_field_2, index_field_2, 5, const, 1, Using index
2, SUBQUERY, my_table, ref, index_field_1, index_field_1, 5, const, 1, Using index

so really missing here is the index for field_3 and field_2:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD KEY `index_field_2_and_3` (`field_2`,`field_3`);
```

After adding the double-field index "Using Where" changes to "Using where; **Using index**"

Comment: how is this different than what he said in the question?

Comment: It's only ONE query, otherwise the optimizer can not guess what's coming next.

Comment: This is very good, it makes use of the indexes as I needed. You are right regarding to the double-key index, I forgot to add it to the table.

Comment: @Hogan in the example query in my question it doesn't use the indexes.

Comment: Just a remark: The index `index_field_2_and_3` will have to be read completely (full index scan). So, yes, this is a solution where no full table scan is performed and all access is done via indexes. However, this can take much longer than simply reading the table without using any index. So the question is properly answered, but if it is speed fguillen is after, then he may have asked the wrong question ;-)

Comment: You guys are funny.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine you can do it more effectively than querying every index separately. In scenarios popping into my mind I would use something along these lines:

```
select "field_1_is_2" as criteria, count(*) from my_table where field_1 = 2
union all
select "field_2_is_4" as criteria, count(*) from my_table where field_2 = 4
union all
select "field_3_is_5" as criteria, count(*) from my_table where field_3 = 5
union all
select "fields_combined" as criteria, count(*) from my_table where field_3 != 2 and field_2 != 2;
```

returning me every value on separate row:

```
criteria    count(*)
field_1_is_2    1
field_2_is_4    1
field_3_is_5    1
fields_combined 3
```

Comment: This is very good too, it also makes use of the indexes, I am choosing the @ralf.w answer because he manage to return the results as in a more classical format.

Answer (score 1):

With `where field_3 != 2 and field_2 != 2` it is very, very unlikely that one of your indexes will be used. `field_3 != 2` should be true for an awful lot of records. Same for `field_2 != 2`. The DBMS won't scan the indexes to get, say, 80 percent of the records with one criteria and another 70% percent with the other and then intersect the sets. It will rather simply read the table once from beginning to end, i.e. perform a full table scan.

As it will read the whole table for this count, you shouldn't get the other counts in separate queries, but get the counts on the fly instead. So the option with conditional sums is the way to go. In standard SQL:

```
select
  count(case when field_1 = 2 then 1 end) as field_1_is_2,
  count(case when field_2 = 4 then 1 end) as field_2_is_4,
  count(case when field_3 = 5 then 1 end) as field_3_is_5,
  count(case when field_3 != 2 and field_2 != 2 then 1 end) as fields_combined
from my_table;
```

In MySQL:

```
select
  sum(field_1 = 2) as field_1_is_2,
  sum(field_2 = 4) as field_2_is_4,
  sum(field_3 = 5) as field_3_is_5,
  sum(field_3 != 2 and field_2 != 2) as fields_combined
from my_table;
```

Comment: But this solution is not making use of any index :/

Comment: You are right regarding to the missing index, I have added an update in my question. It was a mistake, the double index should be there from the beginning to avoid this misunderstanding.

Comment: With the new composite index you can make MySQL use indexes for all counts as ralf.w. has shown in his answer, but it is quite likely that one simple full table scan is faster.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MYSQL Union All command](http://www.oyewiki.com/mysql/mysql-union-clause) . I have create a simillar table and inserted test data.

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|       3 |       1 |       5 |
|       2 |       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |       1 |
|       1 |       4 |       1 |
|       1 |       4 |       2 |
|       1 |       4 |       3 |
|       1 |       4 |       4 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Now the sql query that I am using is

> select count(*) as field_1_is_2 from my_table where field_1 = 2 **union
>   all** select count(*) as field_2_is_4 from my_table where field_2 = 4
>   **union all** select count(*) as field_3_is_5 from my_table where field_3
>   = 5;

This is giving result like

```
+--------------+
| field_1_is_2 |
+--------------+
|            1 |
|            4 |
|            1 |
+--------------+
```

You should be able to get the result as first row, second row and third row. This will harness the power of indexes as well.

Comment: count() should really be count(*) otherwise that doesn't even compile